# Remove LabelBuilder TextAreaBuilder StackPaneBuilder VBoxBuilder

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I want to update the code of this example:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/StackPanebasedwizard.htm

```
package javafxwizard;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.Stack;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.LabelBuilder;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextAreaBuilder;
import javafx.scene.control.Toggle;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPaneBuilder;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBoxBuilder;

public class JavaFXWizard extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new SurveyWizard(stage), 400, 250));
        stage.show();
    }
}

class Wizard extends StackPane {

    private static final int UNDEFINED = -1;
    private ObservableList<WizardPage> pages = FXCollections
            .observableArrayList();
    private Stack<Integer> history = new Stack<>();
    private int curPageIdx = UNDEFINED;

    Wizard(WizardPage... nodes) {
        pages.addAll(nodes);
        navTo(0);
        setStyle("-fx-padding: 10; -fx-background-color: cornsilk;");
    }

    void nextPage() {
        if (hasNextPage()) {
            navTo(curPageIdx + 1);
        }
    }

    void priorPage() {
        if (hasPriorPage()) {
            navTo(history.pop(), false);
        }
    }

    boolean hasNextPage() {
        return (curPageIdx < pages.size() - 1);
    }

    boolean hasPriorPage() {
        return !history.isEmpty();
    }

    void navTo(int nextPageIdx, boolean pushHistory) {
        if (nextPageIdx < 0 || nextPageIdx >= pages.size()) {
            return;
        }
        if (curPageIdx != UNDEFINED) {
            if (pushHistory) {
                history.push(curPageIdx);
            }
        }

        WizardPage nextPage = pages.get(nextPageIdx);
        curPageIdx = nextPageIdx;
        getChildren().clear();
        getChildren().add(nextPage);
        nextPage.manageButtons();
    }

    void navTo(int nextPageIdx) {
        navTo(nextPageIdx, true);
    }

    void navTo(String id) {
        Node page = lookup("#" + id);
        if (page != null) {
            int nextPageIdx = pages.indexOf(page);
            if (nextPageIdx != UNDEFINED) {
                navTo(nextPageIdx);
            }
        }
    }

    public void finish() {
    }

    public void cancel() {
    }
}

/**
 * basic wizard page class
 */
abstract class WizardPage extends VBox {

    Button priorButton = new Button("_Previous");
    Button nextButton = new Button("N_ext");
    Button cancelButton = new Button("Cancel");
    Button finishButton = new Button("_Finish");

    WizardPage(String title) {
        getChildren().add(
                LabelBuilder.create().text(title)
                .style("-fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-padding: 0 0 5 0;").build());
        setId(title);
        setSpacing(5);
        setStyle("-fx-padding:10; -fx-background-color: honeydew; -fx-border-color: derive(honeydew, -30%); -fx-border-width: 3;");

        Region spring = new Region();
        VBox.setVgrow(spring, Priority.ALWAYS);
        getChildren().addAll(getContent(), spring, getButtons());

        priorButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                priorPage();
            }
        });
        nextButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                nextPage();
            }
        });
        cancelButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                getWizard().cancel();
            }
        });
        finishButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                getWizard().finish();
            }
        });
    }

    HBox getButtons() {
        Region spring = new Region();
        HBox.setHgrow(spring, Priority.ALWAYS);
        HBox buttonBar = new HBox(5);
        cancelButton.setCancelButton(true);
        finishButton.setDefaultButton(true);
        buttonBar.getChildren().addAll(spring, priorButton, nextButton,
                cancelButton, finishButton);
        return buttonBar;
    }

    abstract Parent getContent();

    boolean hasNextPage() {
        return getWizard().hasNextPage();
    }

    boolean hasPriorPage() {
        return getWizard().hasPriorPage();
    }

    void nextPage() {
        getWizard().nextPage();
    }

    void priorPage() {
        getWizard().priorPage();
    }

    void navTo(String id) {
        getWizard().navTo(id);
    }

    Wizard getWizard() {
        return (Wizard) getParent();
    }

    public void manageButtons() {
        if (!hasPriorPage()) {
            priorButton.setDisable(true);
        }

        if (!hasNextPage()) {
            nextButton.setDisable(true);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This class shows a satisfaction survey
 */
class SurveyWizard extends Wizard {

    Stage owner;

    public SurveyWizard(Stage owner) {
        super(new ComplaintsPage(), new MoreInformationPage(), new ThanksPage());
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        System.out.println("Had complaint? "
                + SurveyData.instance.hasComplaints.get());
        if (SurveyData.instance.hasComplaints.get()) {
            System.out.println("Complaints: "
                    + (SurveyData.instance.complaints.get().isEmpty() ? "No Details"
                    : "\n" + SurveyData.instance.complaints.get()));
        }
        owner.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        System.out.println("Cancelled");
        owner.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Simple placeholder class for the customer entered survey response.
 */
class SurveyData {

    BooleanProperty hasComplaints = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    StringProperty complaints = new SimpleStringProperty();
    static SurveyData instance = new SurveyData();
}

/**
 * This class determines if the user has complaints. If not, it jumps to the
 * last page of the wizard.
 */
class ComplaintsPage extends WizardPage {

    private RadioButton yes;
    private RadioButton no;
    private ToggleGroup options = new ToggleGroup();

    public ComplaintsPage() {
        super("Complaints");

        nextButton.setDisable(true);
        finishButton.setDisable(true);
        yes.setToggleGroup(options);
        no.setToggleGroup(options);
        options.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> observableValue,
                    Toggle oldToggle, Toggle newToggle) {
                nextButton.setDisable(false);
                finishButton.setDisable(false);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    Parent getContent() {
        yes = new RadioButton("Yes");
        no = new RadioButton("No");
        SurveyData.instance.hasComplaints.bind(yes.selectedProperty());
        return VBoxBuilder.create().spacing(5)
                .children(new Label("Do you have complaints?"), yes, no).build();
    }

    @Override
    void nextPage() {
        // If they have complaints, go to the normal next page
        if (options.getSelectedToggle().equals(yes)) {
            super.nextPage();
        } else {
            // No complaints? Short-circuit the rest of the pages
            navTo("Thanks");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This page gathers more information about the complaint
 */
class MoreInformationPage extends WizardPage {

    public MoreInformationPage() {
        super("More Info");
    }

    @Override
    Parent getContent() {
        TextArea textArea = TextAreaBuilder.create().wrapText(true).build();
        nextButton.setDisable(true);
        textArea.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue,
                    String oldValue, String newValue) {
                nextButton.setDisable(newValue.isEmpty());
            }
        });
        SurveyData.instance.complaints.bind(textArea.textProperty());
        return VBoxBuilder.create().spacing(5)
                .children(new Label("Please enter your complaints."), textArea).build();
    }
}

/**
 * This page thanks the user for taking the survey
 */
class ThanksPage extends WizardPage {

    public ThanksPage() {
        super("Thanks");
    }

    @Override
    Parent getContent() {
        StackPane stack = StackPaneBuilder.create().children(new Label("Thanks!"))
                .build();
        VBox.setVgrow(stack, Priority.ALWAYS);
        return stack;
    }
}
```

Can you help me to update the code? In Java 8 `LabelBuilder TextAreaBuilder StackPaneBuilder VBoxBuilder` are obsolete code?

Can you help me to simplify the code and update it for Java 8?

Comment: It shouldn't be so difficult. First try to understand how builders work, then you will see how it can be easily refactored. The Builder pattern is common in programming languages, so sooner or later you will encounter them again.

Comment: Could you please assist for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the same code, but without the builders... Buts its the same Logic:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.Stack;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.Toggle;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class JavaFXWizard extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new SurveyWizard(stage), 400, 250));
        stage.show();
    }
}

class Wizard extends StackPane {

    private static final int UNDEFINED = -1;
    private ObservableList<WizardPage> pages = FXCollections
            .observableArrayList();
    private Stack<Integer> history = new Stack<>();
    private int curPageIdx = UNDEFINED;

    Wizard(WizardPage... nodes) {
        pages.addAll(nodes);
        navTo(0);
        setStyle("-fx-padding: 10; -fx-background-color: cornsilk;");
    }

    void nextPage() {
        if (hasNextPage()) {
            navTo(curPageIdx + 1);
        }
    }

    void priorPage() {
        if (hasPriorPage()) {
            navTo(history.pop(), false);
        }
    }

    boolean hasNextPage() {
        return (curPageIdx < pages.size() - 1);
    }

    boolean hasPriorPage() {
        return !history.isEmpty();
    }

    void navTo(int nextPageIdx, boolean pushHistory) {
        if (nextPageIdx < 0 || nextPageIdx >= pages.size()) {
            return;
        }
        if (curPageIdx != UNDEFINED) {
            if (pushHistory) {
                history.push(curPageIdx);
            }
        }

        WizardPage nextPage = pages.get(nextPageIdx);
        curPageIdx = nextPageIdx;
        getChildren().clear();
        getChildren().add(nextPage);
        nextPage.manageButtons();
    }

    void navTo(int nextPageIdx) {
        navTo(nextPageIdx, true);
    }

    void navTo(String id) {
        Node page = lookup("#" + id);
        if (page != null) {
            int nextPageIdx = pages.indexOf(page);
            if (nextPageIdx != UNDEFINED) {
                navTo(nextPageIdx);
            }
        }
    }

    public void finish() {
    }

    public void cancel() {
    }
}

/**
 * basic wizard page class
 */
abstract class WizardPage extends VBox {

    Button priorButton = new Button("_Previous");
    Button nextButton = new Button("N_ext");
    Button cancelButton = new Button("Cancel");
    Button finishButton = new Button("_Finish");

    WizardPage(String title) {
        Label label = new Label(title);
        label.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-padding: 0 0 5 0;");
        getChildren().add(label);
        setId(title);
        setSpacing(5);
        setStyle("-fx-padding:10; -fx-background-color: honeydew; -fx-border-color: derive(honeydew, -30%); -fx-border-width: 3;");

        Region spring = new Region();
        VBox.setVgrow(spring, Priority.ALWAYS);
        getChildren().addAll(getContent(), spring, getButtons());

        priorButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                priorPage();
            }
        });
        nextButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                nextPage();
            }
        });
        cancelButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                getWizard().cancel();
            }
        });
        finishButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                getWizard().finish();
            }
        });
    }

    HBox getButtons() {
        Region spring = new Region();
        HBox.setHgrow(spring, Priority.ALWAYS);
        HBox buttonBar = new HBox(5);
        cancelButton.setCancelButton(true);
        finishButton.setDefaultButton(true);
        buttonBar.getChildren().addAll(spring, priorButton, nextButton,
                cancelButton, finishButton);
        return buttonBar;
    }

    abstract Parent getContent();

    boolean hasNextPage() {
        return getWizard().hasNextPage();
    }

    boolean hasPriorPage() {
        return getWizard().hasPriorPage();
    }

    void nextPage() {
        getWizard().nextPage();
    }

    void priorPage() {
        getWizard().priorPage();
    }

    void navTo(String id) {
        getWizard().navTo(id);
    }

    Wizard getWizard() {
        return (Wizard) getParent();
    }

    public void manageButtons() {
        if (!hasPriorPage()) {
            priorButton.setDisable(true);
        }

        if (!hasNextPage()) {
            nextButton.setDisable(true);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This class shows a satisfaction survey
 */
class SurveyWizard extends Wizard {

    Stage owner;

    public SurveyWizard(Stage owner) {
        super(new ComplaintsPage(), new MoreInformationPage(), new ThanksPage());
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        System.out.println("Had complaint? "
                + SurveyData.instance.hasComplaints.get());
        if (SurveyData.instance.hasComplaints.get()) {
            System.out
                    .println("Complaints: "
                            + (SurveyData.instance.complaints.get().isEmpty() ? "No Details"
                                    : "\n"
                                            + SurveyData.instance.complaints
                                                    .get()));
        }
        owner.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        System.out.println("Cancelled");
        owner.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Simple placeholder class for the customer entered survey response.
 */
class SurveyData {

    BooleanProperty hasComplaints = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    StringProperty complaints = new SimpleStringProperty();
    static SurveyData instance = new SurveyData();
}

/**
 * This class determines if the user has complaints. If not, it jumps to the
 * last page of the wizard.
 */
class ComplaintsPage extends WizardPage {

    private RadioButton yes;
    private RadioButton no;
    private ToggleGroup options = new ToggleGroup();

    public ComplaintsPage() {
        super("Complaints");

        nextButton.setDisable(true);
        finishButton.setDisable(true);
        yes.setToggleGroup(options);
        no.setToggleGroup(options);
        options.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(
                new ChangeListener<Toggle>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(
                            ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> observableValue,
                            Toggle oldToggle, Toggle newToggle) {
                        nextButton.setDisable(false);
                        finishButton.setDisable(false);
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    Parent getContent() {
        yes = new RadioButton("Yes");
        no = new RadioButton("No");
        SurveyData.instance.hasComplaints.bind(yes.selectedProperty());
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setSpacing(5);
        vBox.getChildren()
                .addAll(new Label("Do you have complaints?"), yes, no);
        return vBox;
    }

    @Override
    void nextPage() {
        // If they have complaints, go to the normal next page
        if (options.getSelectedToggle().equals(yes)) {
            super.nextPage();
        } else {
            // No complaints? Short-circuit the rest of the pages
            navTo("Thanks");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This page gathers more information about the complaint
 */
class MoreInformationPage extends WizardPage {

    public MoreInformationPage() {
        super("More Info");
    }

    @Override
    Parent getContent() {
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setWrapText(true);

        nextButton.setDisable(true);
        textArea.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(
                    ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue,
                    String oldValue, String newValue) {
                nextButton.setDisable(newValue.isEmpty());
            }
        });
        SurveyData.instance.complaints.bind(textArea.textProperty());
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setSpacing(5);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Please enter your complaints."),
                textArea);
        return vBox;
    }
}

/**
 * This page thanks the user for taking the survey
 */
class ThanksPage extends WizardPage {

    public ThanksPage() {
        super("Thanks");
    }

    @Override
    Parent getContent() {
        StackPane stack = new StackPane();
        stack.getChildren().add(new Label("Thanks!"));
        VBox.setVgrow(stack, Priority.ALWAYS);
        return stack;
    }
}
```

Comment: How I can reorganize the code in a other way: I would like to remove abstract Java class.

Comment: Why would you like to remove it? Its a good practice to hace an abstract class, when you want to make sure that no instance of it its created... 
Is there a specific reason why you would want to do this?

Comment: I just want to make the code much more simple for understand.

Comment: tomorrow ill see how you might simplify it more... but to my understanding its a decent solution. But the best thing you can do is probably create a class diagram to understand better the code.

Comment: I dont think there is another simple option as this, and extensible... You might want to create that class driagram.

Comment: I see here that most of the configuration is inserted into default Java constructor like `Wizard(WizardPage... nodes) {.....}` I would like to rewrite this code.

Comment: The thing is that all the pages share that behaviour, so if you dont put it in a parent class, you would repeat it.